# mysql_fetch assoc refuses to return password row. Help needed

Tags: php

The username row comes out perfectly but the password row refuses to come through.

I am at a loss here.

Does anybody know what the solution is?

here is my code::

```
<?php

//Mass include file
include ("includes/mass.php");

//This is the login script
//Grabbing the login values and storing them

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$submit   = $_POST['submit'];

if (isset($submit))
{
    if (strlen($username)<2) // put || ($username==(same as value on the database)
    {
        echo ("<br>You must enter a longer username</br>");
    }
    elseif (strlen($password)<=6)
    {
        echo ("<br>You must enter a longer password<br>");
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username'";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

        if ($numrows != 0)
        {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
                $dbusername = $row['username'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password'];         

            if ($dbusername == $username && $dbpassword == $password)
            {
                echo "your in!";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Wrong info";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            die ("That username doesnt exist");
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You should never keep unhashed passwords in the database, and you should use prepared statements.  The above code is completely vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Yes i know. I do it like this initially for testing. When i get the functionality right i focus on security. 

What do you mean by prepared statements though?

Comment: Since you are new to SO, I would like to tell you that you can accept an answer that helped you the most by clicking the 'right mark' next to the answer.

Comment: Thank you gameover. I just ticked it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a missing parenthesis after the while.

Both

```
$dbusername = $row['username'];
$dbpassword = $row['password'];
```

Should be within the while loop which is not the case.

You need to do something like:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    $dbusername = $row['username'];
    $dbpassword = $row['password'];           

    if ($dbusername == $username && $dbpassword == $password) {
        echo "your in!";
    }
....
```

Adding to what Matthew has said:

You should not show messages like "username doesnt exist" to the user. This provides valuable information to a hacker who wants to break in. In case the user provides a wrong username and/or wrong password, you should display "invalid username or password".

Answer (score 0):

Your script would fail if username is not unique. Is that perhaps the case?

Apart from that, storing passwords as plain text and not cleaning user input: very bad ideas...

**Edit:** By the way, why don´t you check for a valid username / password combination in the query itself:

```
... WHERE username='" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "'
    AND password='" . some_hashing_function($password) .  "'";
```

**Another edit:** You have to look carefully at what is happening; my initial answer (non-unique user-id) could be a problem, but @codaddict's answer could already solve your problem.

Basically, what your statement is like without the curly braces is like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    $dbusername = $row['username'];
    $dbpassword = $row['password'];         
    ....
```

is the same to php as:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $dbusername = $row['username'];
}
$dbpassword = $row['password'];
...
```

so by the time you want to fill your $dbpassword, $row is already empty.

Comment: Hi Jeroen

Thanks for your input. This script is for logging in. Not registration. Which is why i havent included the hashing.

Comment: Tapha, that does not matter, when you store the password at registration, you should store a hash and to match at the time of login, you also need the hash to compare. In case you have a database full of plain text passwords, it is easy to hash all passwords all at once; if necessary in a new field and remove the plain text passwords when everything is working.

Comment: (smacks head) thank you. i make these mistakes. :) im a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

```
I like the suggestion about the {} that normally encompasses the code that occurs in a while loop. Id replace 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
                $dbusername = $row['username'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password']; 

with

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
   $dbusername = $row['username'];
   $dbpassword = $row['password']; 
}
// this lets the loop finish so $dbusername and $dbpassword are potentially set
// so you can contine with your if statements

Another thing to check is your html - check your password field looks something
like <input type="password" name="password" />

You could always try echo $password; immediately after $_POST['password'] to see 
if it existed in the first place. Then echo any of your variables after they have
been set to see if they exist.
```

Comment: The guy didn't ask but from his code its looks like he might not be aware of these dangerous mistakes.